# Linq complex Inner Join

Tags: c#, linq, inner-join

I want to join my data with linq inner join as:

```cs
[DataContract]
public class Data
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public List<DataResultObject> Row { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class DataResultObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string VALUE { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TYPE { get; set; }

}

List<Data> follow = (List<Data>)dataset_cache.Get("follow");//364 rows
List<Data> icerik = (List<Data>)dataset_cache.Get("icerik");//134854 rows

List<Data> follow_icerik = icerik.Join(follow,
                i => i.Row.Where(w => w.NAME == "CrawlSourceId").Select(s => s.VALUE),
                f => f.Row.Where(w => w.NAME == "crawl_source_id").Select(s => s.VALUE),
                (i, f) =>
                    new Data
                    {
                        Row = i.Row.Concat(nf.Row).ToList()
                    }
                ).Take(5).ToList();
```

But it returns empty, how to use inner join when we have list in "on" clause ?

[image: table 1 data image]

[image: table 2 data image]

Comment: Can you write it with basic loops? It will help you. Also, Can you add a [mcve]?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] **including sample data**.

Comment: I need to use linq, no prblem with sql.

Comment: @CanerUnutkan Post your data as a POCO

Comment: You can probably use conversion to string for this `String.Join("\0", i.Row.Where(w => w.NAME == "CrawlSourceId").Select(s => s.VALUE).OrderBy(o => o))`. But you should definitely do what mjwills said to get a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
List<Data> follow_icerik = icerik.Concat(
                icerik.SelectMany(e => e.Row)
                                 .Where(w => w.NAME == "CrawlSourceId")
                                 .Join(follow.SelectMany(e => e.Row)
                                              .Where(w => w.NAME == "crawl_source_id"),
                i => i.VALUE,
                f => f.VALUE,
                (i, f) =>
                     new List<DataResultObject> { i, f }
                ).Select(e => new Data { Row = e })
).ToList();
```

EDIT:

`icerik.SelectMany(e=>e.Row)` - select rows with data which we are needed

`icerik.SelectMany(e=>e.Row).Where(w => w.NAME == "CrawlSourceId")` - filter this data

`...  Join(...` - join filtered data

In `Join` we also have to filter data before join: `follow.SelectMany(e=>e.Row)                                              .Where(w => w.NAME == "crawl_source_id")`

`i => i.VALUE,
 f => f.VALUE,` - fields on which we join data.

Comment: get the error on  w.NAME : "List<contract.DataResultObject>' does not contain a definition for 'NAME' and no extension method 'NAME' accepting a first argument of type 'List<contract.DataResultObject>,"

Comment: I edited a litle and worked but result has only joined colums , other colums are missin.
new Data
                    {
                        Row = new List<DataResultObject> {
                            i,f
                        }
                    }

Comment: Explain what result you want because it is not clear from your question description.

Comment: Edited again. Hope it is that you are needed.

Comment: Now the error is : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Service.contract.Data>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Service.contract.Data>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Edited. Add `.ToList()` at the end.

Comment: retruned same of icerik as result :/

Comment: Check what `Join` returns. If it returns not empty collection then concat return you concatenated data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.8